# ¿Se puede detener la macro completa desde una UserForm?

Tags: vba

Yo tengo un proyecto en VBA en el que ya estoy preparando las salidas por errores y hay un error que se puede generar en la inicialización de una **UserForm**.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        On Error GoTo initiate
        'Acá puede ocurrir un error
        nameNUIP.Caption = .VLookup(...) _ 
                   + " " + .VLookup(...) 'Lo pongo así porque no es necesaria la información
        BirthDate.Caption = .VLookup(...)
        RegDate.Caption = .VLookup(...)
        Place.Caption = .VLookup(...) _
               + ", " + .VLookup(...)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
Exit Sub

'Control de errores
initiate: 'Acá se viene el código si ocurre el error
    MsgBox Title:="NUIP ERROR:" & Err.Number, _
           Prompt:="Fallo en la búsqueda del NUIP." & vbNewLine & "¿Seguro que ya se registró?", _
           Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Cuando el código pasa a la etiqueta `initiate` por no encontrar datos, aparece la ventana con el mensaje como es previsto, pero luego de aceptar, **la macro continua y muestra la UserForm**, cosa que no quiero. Yo deseo que si ocurre el error, se deje de ejecutar la macro, pero que no se cierre el libro.

¿Es posible cerrar todo por ocurrir un error? ¿Qué métodos podría usar para esto?

PD: Mi versión de Excel es 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurren dos opciones:

#### 1. Descargar el formulario en el evento Activate

En vez de usar el evento `Initialize()` "colgar" el código de `Activate()` y en caso de error descargar el formulario mediante `Unload Me`. Lamentablemente no podemos hacer lo mismo en el `Initialize`, por que en esa instancia el formulario no ha terminado de instanciarse.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

    Dim Dummy As Integer

    On Error GoTo Error
    Dummy = 1 / 0

    Exit Sub

Error:
    MsgBox Title:="NUIP ERROR:" & Err.Number, _
           Prompt:="Fallo en la búsqueda del NUIP." & vbNewLine & "¿Seguro que ya se registró?", _
           Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbExclamation
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

La único observable es que el formulario se abrirá de todas formas para luego cerrarse en caso de error, si no se quiere esto, entonces el siguiente punto sería mejor:

#### 2. Crear en un modulo una rutina para abrir el formulario y en esta hacer el control que se quiere hacer:

```
Private Sub Load_UserForm1()

    Dim Dummy As Integer

    On Error GoTo Error
    Dummy = 1 / 0

    UserForm1.Show

    Exit Sub

Error:
    MsgBox Title:="NUIP ERROR:" & Err.Number, _
           Prompt:="Fallo en la búsqueda del NUIP." & vbNewLine & "¿Seguro que ya se registró?", _
           Buttons:=vbOKOnly + vbExclamation

End Sub
```

Si no existiera error, se abrirá el formulario al invocar `UserForm1.Show` y en caso de error solo se muestra el mensaje de error. Por supuesto hay que modificar la lógica actual para que la carga del Formulario se realice únicamente invocando nuestra rutina `Load_UserForm1`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta :D